# Vaadin-14: checking if client is a mobile device

Tags: java, mobile, vaadin, vaadin14

i am developing a webapp and i want to separate UIs for desktops and mobile devices, so i want to check wether the client using my app is a mobile device or not.

I tried to look online for official documentation or vaadin forum , but i couldn't find any useful information, since almost all of the solutions proposed in those answers are not implementable any more (the methods were removed).

Comment: Are you trying to change only how the webapp is displayed (i.e. collapsible menu, general appearance and layout), or will there be functional differences depending user device (i.e. a button does a completely different thing when on mobile)?

Comment: Just the appearance. The UIs will call the same methods

Comment: Are you aware of [CSS `@media` queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)?

Comment: Nope, i'm not quite into CSS. I was trying to find a way around it.

Comment: I know why you try to avoid it, but in this case you will not be able hide from CSS. Using CSS media queries is how you achieve what you want. I'm sorry that I won't be able to write an answer that would hold up to my expectations, because I'm not too well versed with CSS either. But you can find many good tutorials if you are looking for a "responsive website using CSS media query" online.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getBrowser()` to see if your client is a phone or not.

```
public  boolean isMobileDevice() {
    WebBrowser webBrowser = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getBrowser();
    return webBrowser.isAndroid() || webBrowser.isIPhone() || webBrowser.isWindowsPhone();
}
```

Comment: I really liked the solution, but unfortunatly it des not work always. I emulated the Pixel 2 XL on Chrome and it's not working

Comment: What kind of emulator are you using? Are you using Developer Tools of Chrome on Windows? If so, you should change your user-agent as explained  here: https://winaero.com/blog/change-user-agent-chrome/.

Comment: @FedericoAndreoli it works always, the Emulator is sending the wrong `user-agent`, you should accept that answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested i found a way around CSS, even if i think it's a bit limited.

I used `HttpServletRequest`, `VaadinService` and `VaadinServletRequest`: I basically checked if words like "Mobile", "iPhone" or "Android" are in the request.

It's not an elegant solution, but it works. This is the code:

```
public static boolean isPhone(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    return (url.contains("iPhone") || url.contains("Android"));
}
```